# Ember cannot display JSON from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember CLI app that uses Rails as a backend. The code appears to be fine, and if I visit `localhost:3000`, it displays the JSON output just fine. However, Ember does not display this data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// ember/app/adapters/application.js

import DS from "ember-data";
export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});

// ember/app/controllers/data_keys.js

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name']
});

// ember/app/models/data_key.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

// ember/app/routes/data_keys/index.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'data_keys',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.all('data_key');
  }
});

// rails/app/controllers/api/data_keys_controller.rb

class Api::DataKeysController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: DataKey.all
  end
end

// rails/app/serializers/data_key_serializer.rb

class DataKeySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end

// rails/config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do 
    resources :data_keys
  end
end
```

To run the app, I run the Rails side with `rails s`, then in another terminal tab I run `ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000`.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I know that Ember CLI version 0.0.39 had proxy uses, but I'm using Ember CLI 0.0.40.

```
ember -v
version: 0.0.40
node: 0.10.28
npm: 1.4.21
```

Here's an example of the JSON returned by the server:

```
{ 
  "data_keys": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bar"
  }] 
}
```

Comment: the namespace: 'api' appends a /api in your backend so in your ruby, you must serve it on /api also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you use [DS.Store#all](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_all) you're only filtering the records that are already in the store. You'll want to use [DS.Store#find](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find) in order to get the records from the server.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'data_keys',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('data_key');
  }
});
```

Also, your ember files should use dashes rather than underscores.